# how to get data-binding to work with ok and cancel buttons

Tags: c#, data-binding

I am trying to create a reusable Settings dialog and I want to bind the controls in the dialog to the Properties.Settings built into Visual Studio.

This is the code I use to bind each control as I iterate through them:

```
Control.DataBindings.Add(new Binding(strProperty, Properties.Settings.Default, Control.Name, false, DataSourceUpdateMode.Never));
```

Where strProperty is resolved to the appropriate Property of the control to bind with. Note the update mode: DataSourceUpdateMode.Never. More on that in a minute.

This code works to bind the control to the setting. When the dialog opens, all the controls display the appropriate values. The problem is with getting the DataSource, i.e. the Properties.Settings, to update properly, and at the right time. When the DataSourceUpdateMode is set to "OnPropertyChanged", it works as expected to update the values, but this isn't the desired behavior of a dialog. You don't want to update until the OK button is pressed, not as soon as the value in the control has changed. 
After reading all the documentation I could find, it seemed to me that the best way would be set the DataSourceUpdateMode to "Never" and then when the OK button is pressed I would iterate through all of the controls and call Control.DataBinding[0].WriteValue() to manually update all the properties. But when I did that I found that after the first control was updated, every single one of the remaining controls would immediately revert to it's previous value!

```
public void UpdateDataSource(Control.ControlCollection ctrls)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in ctrls)
    {
        if (ctrl.Controls.Count > 0)
        {
             UpdateDataSource(ctrl.Controls);
        }

        if (ctrl.DataBindings != null)
        {
             foreach (Binding binding in ctrl.DataBindings)
             {
                 binding.WriteValue();
             }
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried something using the DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation flag. I set every control's CausesValidation property to false to prevent updates from occurring before the OK button is pressed. Then when the OK button is pressed I iterate through all the controls and set the CausesValidation flag back to true and then call the form's ValidateChildren() method. This has the desired effect of causing the validation to occur on all of the controls after, and only after the OK button is pressed but the result is exactly the same as when I used the binding.WriteValue(). Immediately after the first control updates the data source, every other bound control on the form reverts back to its original value.